# Restrict python exec acess to one directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-exec

I have a python script which executes a string of code with the *exec* function. I need a way to restrict the read/write access of the script to the current directory. How can I achieve this?

Or, is there a way to restrict the python script's environment directly through the command line so that when I run the interpreter, it does not allow writes out of the directory? Can I do that using a virtualenv? How?

So basically, my app is a web portal where people can write and execute python apps and get a response - and I've hosted this on heroku. Now there might be multiple users with multiple folders and no user should have access to other's folders or even system files and folders. The permissions should be determined by the user on the nodejs app (a web app) and not a local user. How do I achieve that?

Comment: There are so many ways to access a file in Python that it's impractical to lock them all down. Even if there was a way, there's the possibility of an exploit in Python itself that might let you get around it. To be really sure you need to run Python in an environment that provides the restrictions outside of Python itself.

Comment: And how do I run python itself in a restricted environment then? Can I limit the access of a python virtualenv?

Comment: If I knew that, I would have left an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Execute the code as a user that only owns that specific directory and has no permissions anywhere else?

However- if you do not completely trust the source of code, you should simply not be using `exec` under any circumstances.  Remember, say you came up with a python solution... the exec code could literally undo whatever restrictions you put on it before doing its nefarious deeds.  If you tell us the problem you're trying to solve, we can probably come up with a better idea.

Comment: To further add to your answer, it sounds like this is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick response. So basically, my app is a web portal where people can write and execute python apps and get a response - and I've hosted this on heroku. Now there might be multiple users with multiple folders and no user should have access to other's folders or even system files and folders. How do I achieve that?

Comment: @VinitJogani You're going about this the wrong way. Don't allow users to execute arbitrary Python code. Instead, set things up as microservices.

Comment: If I were going to do this, I would look at one of the javascript Python implementations to have the code execution be entirely client side.  Trying to do it on your side without blowing up your server will require a lot of security work.

Comment: @JackManey, But the application is like a Codecademy website where it is necessary for the users to execute Python code.

Answer (score 2):

The question boils down to: How can I safely execute the code I don't trust.
You can't.
Either you know what the code does or you don't execute it.
You can have an isolated environment for your process, for example with docker. But the use cases are far away from executing unsafe code.